# Who sold Amazon the rights for the Lord of the Rings TV deal?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

As stated in the title. Bonus points if you can explain what exactly is covered in the TV rights; specifically, if the rights cover late Third Age only or the whole Legendarium.

Note: I see a disupted answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129237/has-tolkiens-estate-ever-sold-the-rights-to-adaptations-of-any-tolkien-works); however the linked Amazon press release does not answer the question in the title, so I'm looking for confirmation from another source.

Comment: @Möoz I mean....I linked that question in my post and explained that it doesn't provide an answer...what more do you want?

Comment: How does the following *not* answer your question? "*. The upcoming Amazon Prime Original will be produced by Amazon Studios in cooperation with the Tolkien Estate and Trust, HarperCollins and New Line Cinema, a division of Warner Bros. Entertainment.*"

Comment: @kingledion If you need more details, I suggest you ask the OP in the other answer for clarification. Asking a whole new question to cover a slightly different point seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: Even if you don't deem this a duplicate it would be primarily opinion based as the press release information hasn't been released yet. However it is extremely unlikely (as long as Christopher is alive) that any new rights to more material has been sold.

Comment: @Edlothiad It doesn't answer the question, because neither HarperCollins nor New Line Cinema evidently owned the rights for TV, and as you said, Christopher seems very reluctant to sell new rights. So what really happened? Also, why is there a requirement that an answer be available this very second? If this question can't be answered for a few weeks, why not wait?

Comment: Well, considering we have a re-open feature. We close questions with answers that come up in the future as "Primarily Opinion Based" (because that's what they are) and when the info becomes available someone casts a re-open vote or asks to have it re-opened and it gets re-opened.

Comment: Here's the relevant [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)

Comment: @kingledion "What exactly happened?" Well, apparently Amazon paid $200 million (maybe more, maybe a bit less) simply for the rights. That is *a lot of money*.

Comment: @Edlothiad Thank you for the meta link

Comment: @BCdotWEB the bidding war went to an apparent $250mil, if they got all the rights, that’s a steal, if it’s the same as before, that’s an overpay.

Comment: Christopher Tolkien resigned from his position as director of the Tolkien Estate two months prior to this announcement, so it probably wasn't him.

Comment: @Edlothiad $200+ million isn't a steal. That's an insane amount of money to spend *on rights*.

Comment: @BCdotWEB depends what you get the rights for, if you're getting the entire legendarium, or even just the Silm and UT it's an utter steal, considering you can make, adapt, add countless hours of film/TV and make back WAY more than the your initial investment.